# How retrieve next 30 days data from database?

Tags: php, mysql

Please anyone can tell me the query to retrieve next 30 days data from database starting from today? Its a database users can upload upto next 90 days data.

Comment: Surely the `next` thirty days of data doesn't exist yet? ;-)

Comment: ok... if its an event related database... and users can insert thier events upto next 90 days...???

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: Thank you very much.... I am storing the date in the format 'D, d M, Y'..... Is it possible using this date format???

Comment: Why are you storing the date as a string instead of in a DATE column? Store data as data, do formatting at output. You should change your program, but if you must, you can coerce your string into a date with [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: I need input and output in the same format 'D, d M, Y'.... Thats why i made it as a string...

Comment: That's irrelevant to how you store it. You are doing it wrong, and storing it as a string means MySQL cannot use an index to efficiently answer this query.

Comment: Input is doing with the help of a calendar... its given format is 'D, d M, Y'... its stores directly to database and retrieve $today=date('D, d M, Y');$sql = select * from database where day = '$today';

Comment: Neat, **still irrelevant**. Take the date it gives you and insert it into a DATE column using [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.... I am storing the date in the format 'D, d M, Y'..... Is it possible using this date format???

Comment: Is the data type varchar? Or date / datetime? Should work if it's date / datetime

Comment: You can use `NOW()` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're storing your dates as integers (unix epoch) instead of timestamps you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wherever WHERE startdate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND startdate <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 2592000;
```

This is assuming those 30 days consist of 2.592.000 seconds. Similar code is possible using the timestamps.